# How can I find the ratio?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a tag cloud and since it's for a large site I'm saving the counts in a table to avoid counting everything with each request, here it is:

```
CREATE TABLE `counts` (
  `name` CHAR(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `total` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `locale_id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`,`type`,`locale_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `counts` (`name`, `total`, `type`, `locale_id`)
VALUES
    ('k3k3k',888,3,1),
    ('krkrkrkr',333,3,1),
    ('zzxzx',22,3,1);
```

`name` is the tag word and `total` is how many times it is mentioned in the `tag` table. I need to get the percentage of every tag to build the tag cloud.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   select 
     name, 
     total,
     total/(select sum(total) from counts)*100 as percentage
   from counts
```

Comment: I am wondering, will that subquery run on each row in primary source?

Comment: No, as I know it is seen as a scalar, and evaluated once.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT name,(total/(SELECT SUM(total) FROM counts)) * 100 
FROM counts WHERE name = 'k3k3k'
```

You my want to round the result or do some other formatting ...

Answer (score 1):

Normalize! That is, select max count and base all other counts on it.

```
SELECT name, (total / @max_count * 100) percentage
FROM counts, (SELECT @max_count := MAX(total) FROM counts) t1;
```

Result:

```
+----------+------------+
| name     | percentage |
+----------+------------+
| k3k3k    |   100.0000 |
| krkrkrkr |    37.5000 |
| zzxzx    |     2.4775 |
+----------+------------+
```

Or you can use `SUM` instead of `MAX`

```
SELECT name, (total / @max_count * 100) percentage
FROM counts, (SELECT @max_count := SUM(total) FROM counts) t1;


+----------+------------+
| name     | percentage |
+----------+------------+
| k3k3k    |    71.4401 |
| krkrkrkr |    26.7900 |
| zzxzx    |     1.7699 |
+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Why put the sub-query in the `FROM` and not in the previous `SELECT` ?